# How I need to change my paths to use multiple ids from url but not as params?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-3.0

I want to have a URL like this
`127.0.0.1:8000/classesapp/class/1/student/2/statistics/`
so in the backend with a Django class, I will be able to do a raw query using those ids like this:

```
select * 
from statistics
inner join students on statistics.student_id = student.id
inner join class on student.student_class_id = class.id
where class.id = 1 and student.id = 2
```

How I could achieve this? I can't figure out what I need to do.
I tried this but still didn't work.
`class/<int:pk>/students/<int:pk>/statistics`

my paths are:

```
path('class/<int:pk>/', views.ClassesDetailView.as_view(), name="class_detail"),
path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name="about"),
path('class/<int:pk>/', views.ClassesDetailView.as_view(), name="class_detail"),
path('new/', views.ClassesCreateView.as_view(), name="classes_create"),
path('class/<int:pk>/update/', views.ClassesUpdateView.as_view(), name="classes_update"),
path('class/<int:pk>/delete/', views.ClassesDeleteView.as_view(), name="classes_delete"),
path('class/<int:pk>/student/new/', views.StudentsCreateView.as_view(), name="student_create"),
path('students/', views.StudentsListView.as_view(), name="students_list"),
path('student/<int:pk>/', views.StudentsDetailView.as_view(), name="student_detail"),
path('student/<int:pk>/update/', views.StudentsUpdateView.as_view(), name="student_update"),
path('student/<int:pk>/delete/', views.StudentsDeleteView.as_view(), name="student_delete"),
path('student/<int:pk>/statistics/new/', views.StatisticsCreateView.as_view(), name="statistics_create"),
path('statistic/<int:pk>/update/', views.StatisticsUpdateView.as_view(), name="statistic_update"),
path('statistic/<int:pk>/delete/', views.StatisticsDeleteView.as_view(), name="statistic_delete"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items within an angle bracket describe the parameter in the url (cf. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path)). The first is the type and the second is the name of the parameter.
Following this, in your url you have two parameters of type 'int' with the same name 'pk'. You could rename one them, e.g., the first one to 'class_id':

```
class/<int:class_id>/students/<int:pk>/statistics
```

I would recommend to leave the parameter for your model in your class based view (cbv) as 'pk' (In the above example the related model in your cbv would be the one for the students). In your views you are now able to use the variables via, e.g.,

```
self.kwargs['class_id']
```

If you want to reference this url in yout python code, you can use ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/))

```
reverse('name-of-your-url', args=(class_id, student_id,))
```

and in your templates

```
{% url 'name-of-your-url' class_id student_id %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! Really it helped me a lot how I will do it but I would like to ask if I need to change my Class class view because when I use in URL `/class/1/` (in this case is class/<int:pk>/)  when I want to see student details from a student in this class I have this error `Reverse for 'student_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found`. And the last one I need to use self.kwargs['class_id`] in a function?

Comment: 'pk' is the standard name for the parameter. For this, you dont have to change anything. However, for a view, you can change the name via the attribute 'pk_url_kwarg' (cf. [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/)).

Comment: Maybe you have a view 'Class detail'. Therein you display a list of students. If you click on a student, you already have chosen a student. Then the url should look something like this: `/student/<int:pk>/`. Actually, in this case you don't need two parameters in the url.

Comment: I see! Yes, I have a view 'Class detail' and there a list of students if you click a student you can see student details like name, class and also it has a list of statistics for this student. You are right I have a url like you said `/student/<int:pk>/`. If I click a student then the url is `/student/1` not `class/1/student/1/` there is no problem, right? I mean Django knows that this student is in class 1?

Comment: If you have a ForeignKey (or ManyToMany) relation between the Class and Student models, yes.

Comment: Yes, I have a ForeignKey between Class and Student models. Basically I have a class_id(ForeignKey) in the Student model. Ok thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In your model you should name the fk fields (e.g.) just like the other model. For example, in the Student model define `klass = ForeignKey('Klass') [class]. The field class_id will be set by Django. However, in general a student can have 0 or more classes and a class should have 1 or more students. Thus, I would say you will have a ManyToMany relation ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)).